# laravel eloquent get related articles based on a tag

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

I'm a bit confused about how to do the following.

I have a table of articles and a table of tags with a many to many join and a pivot table between the two. I've got the relationships set up in the models

An articles can have more than one tag.

How can I easily(?) obtain a list of related articles for an article based on the tags attached to the current article.

I've tried querying from the tags side as follows:

```
foreach($article->tags()->get() as $tag) {
    $relatedArticles .= Tag::with('articles')
    ->where('id','=', $tag->id)
    ->take(6)
    ->get();

    }
```

This produces a nil response

I'm not sure about how to query from the articles to find articles with the tags dynamically.

So if an article has attached tag1 and tag2 I then want to retrieve all articles which have either tag1 or tag2 attached to them (ideally sorted on article date). The tags will be different for each article and may just be one or many.

Ideally i'd like to do this with an eloquent query but not essential - I'm not sure how to do in mysql either as a starting point.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided you are using Laravel 4.1, you can do something like this using the `whereHas` eloquent method:

```
$tag_ids = $article->tags()->lists('id');
$relatedArticles = Article::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tag_ids) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $tag_ids);
})
->orderBy('created_at')
->take(6)
->get();
```

### Breakdown

There's a few things going on here:

#### lists()

You can use the `lists` method on a select to get just a particular column, we're only concerned with the ID column in this case.

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

#### whereHas()

We're using the new `whereHas` method which you can read.

More more about here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

#### use()

Since the `whereHas` method accepts a closure (or 'anonymous function'), the function doesn't have any access to variables set externally, so we need to send them through to the function. We can do this with `use`.

More information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php